# Laravel join query confusion

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

Very new to laravel and trying to do something simple but keep getting stuck. I have 3 tables

```
countries:
    id
    country

regions:
    id
    region
    country_id

wineries:
    id
    winery
    country_id
    region_id
```

joined together as follows:

```
public function index()
{   
$wineries = Country::join('wineries', 'countries.id', '=', 'wineries.country_id')
    ->join('regions', 'regions.id', '=', 'wineries.region_id')
    ->select('countries.*')
    ->orderBy('countries.country', 'asc')
    ->get() 
    ->unique();
return view('winery.index', compact('wineries'));
}
```

I'm trying to return a table organized by country with each winery listed along with it's region. Countries without wineries are not to be displayed. My Index page, looks like this:

```
   <tbody>
        @foreach ($wineries as $country)
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">{{ $country->country }}</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($country->wineries as $winery)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $winery->winery }}</td> 
                <td>{{ $winery->region }}</td> 
            </tr>   
        @endforeach     
        @endforeach     
    </tbody>
```

All works well except I can't get the associated region for each winery since the region is not a part of the $winery array. Any advice on how to make it a part of array or how to accomplish this using a different query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In laravel you can define relationships for Models. Models represent a Model of data (normally related to a DB table, but not always)

Laravel uses Eloquent for database defining relational tables within PHP. 
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

For your case it sounds like you have three Models
Countries
Region
Wineries

Your counties will have many regions, but a region will only have one country.
Your regions will have many wineries, but a winery will only have one region.

To spec your relationships within Eloquent you want to write the following functions within each

```
(Country)
    public function regions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Region');
    }

(Region)
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Country');
    }

    public function winery()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Region');
    }
```

etc..

From there you can then relate the data via the models. So if you have a Country object and wanted to get the regions you would do

```
$country->regions
```

You might want to wrap this in a loop to print all of the regions

```
foreach($country->regions as $region) {
    echo $region->name;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just to add - it's better to keep the relationships 'flowing down' rather than having the winery related to both a region and country, this keeps the data easier to maintain

Comment: The models were actually set up but I had my logic wrong. Your comment about keeping the relationships 'flowing down' led me to re-examine and fix the relationships and rearrange the query. I had some circular relationships that made this not behave as expected. But it's now working. I'm still using the join queries to retrieve only countries that have wineries. If I switch to using $wineries = Country::all(), the data still displays correctly but every country in the database gets listed. Not sure how to fix that yet but thanks for leading me to solve my first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Define relationships using model. Laravel has Eloquent model in built. It's very easy to query database using that. Learning curve is well worth it.